# Creating a messaging application (Wifi)

Tags: android, wifi, chat, messaging

I'm sort of new to Android application development. I already created a very simple application that turns the device's flashlight on/off.
I'd like to try and create a messaging application where you can chat with your friends when both of you are connected to a Wifi. Sort of like "WhatsApp", "Viber", etc..
I would be really happy if you could give me guidelines and help me get the idea of how to develop such an application.

Thank you so much,
Orel.

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to create server program, that will authenticate username & password and communication between diff users.., etc, and you need to send the response based on the user query. 
For any network communication application consists of two components:

1. Server
2. Client

In the case of WhatsApp android app,its a client application which communicate's with the WhatsApp server.

The server with exchange the data from one client to another client, the client may be desktop, android mobile, iPhone,...etc

Generally chat programs will implemented using  sockets, and its depends upon the architecture and technologies which you will chose.

Comment: So you mean I'll need a server with a database to store all of the messages first?

Comment: Yup. And there is other way but that is not at all suggested.

Comment: I understand. Can you give me a suggestion of an easy app I can develop as a beginner please mate? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using this:

> **ChatServerSide**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ChatServerSide extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

private ServerSocket serverSocket;
Handler updateConversationHandler;
Thread serverThread = null;
Button btnSendMsg;
EditText etInputMessage;
TextView tvOutputMessage;
TextView tvMyIp;
Socket socket;
public static final int SERVERPORT = 6000;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.chat_main_activity);
    iniUi();
    iniListener();

    updateConversationHandler = new Handler();

    this.serverThread = new Thread(new ServerThread());
    this.serverThread.start();
    tvMyIp.setText("Waiting devices on " + getIpAddress());

}

private void iniUi() {
    tvMyIp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMyIp);
    btnSendMsg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendMsg);
    etInputMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etInputMesage);
    tvOutputMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvOutputMessage);
}

private void iniListener() {
    btnSendMsg.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    try {

        String str = etInputMessage.getText().toString();
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                true
        );
        tvOutputMessage.setText(tvOutputMessage.getText().toString() + "You Says: "   + str + "\n");
        etInputMessage.setText("");
        out.println(str);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

class ServerThread implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        socket = null;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

            try {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                CommunicationThread commThread = new CommunicationThread(socket);
                new Thread(commThread).start();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

class CommunicationThread implements Runnable {

    private Socket clientSocket;
    private BufferedReader input;

    public CommunicationThread(Socket clientSocket) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;

        try {
            this.input = new BufferedReader(new   InputStreamReader(this.clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            String read = null;
            try {

                read = input.readLine();
                if (read == null) {
                    read = "Client has leave the chat";
                    socket.close();
                    updateConversationHandler.post(new updateUIThread(read));
                    break;
                }
                updateConversationHandler.post(new updateUIThread("Client Says: " +   read));


        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

}

class updateUIThread implements Runnable {
private String msg;

public updateUIThread(String str) {
    this.msg = str;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    tvOutputMessage.setText(tvOutputMessage.getText().toString() + msg + "\n");
}

}

private String getIpAddress() {
    String ip = "";
    try {
        Enumeration<NetworkInterface> enumNetworkInterfaces = NetworkInterface
                .getNetworkInterfaces();
        while (enumNetworkInterfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
            NetworkInterface networkInterface = enumNetworkInterfaces
                    .nextElement();
            Enumeration<InetAddress> enumInetAddress = networkInterface
                    .getInetAddresses();
            while (enumInetAddress.hasMoreElements()) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumInetAddress.nextElement();

                if (inetAddress.isSiteLocalAddress()) {
                    ip += inetAddress.getHostAddress() + "\n";
                }

            }

        }

    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        ip += "Something Wrong! " + e.toString() + "\n";
    }

    return ip;
  }
}
```

> **ChatClientSide**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class ChatClientSide extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

private Handler handler = new Handler();
private Socket socket;
Button btnSendMsg;
EditText etInputMessage;
TextView tvOutputMessage;
Handler updateConversationHandler;
TextView tvMyIp;
private static final int SERVERPORT = 6000;
private static String SERVER_IP = "";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.chat_main_activity);
    iniUi();
    iniListener();
    SERVER_IP = ActivityMain.ipToConnect;
    updateConversationHandler = new Handler();
    receiveMsg();

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    try {
        socket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    try {
        socket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private String getServerIp(Intent intent) {
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    String ip = bundle.getString("destAdress");
    tvMyIp.setText("Is connected to " + ip);
    return ip;
}

private void iniUi() {
    tvMyIp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMyIp);
    btnSendMsg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendMsg);
    etInputMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etInputMesage);
    tvOutputMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvOutputMessage);
}

private void iniListener() {
    btnSendMsg.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    try {

        String str = etInputMessage.getText().toString();
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                true
        );
        tvOutputMessage.setText(tvOutputMessage.getText().toString() + "You Says: "   + str + "\n");
        etInputMessage.setText("");
        out.println(str);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public void receiveMsg() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final String host = SERVER_IP;

            BufferedReader in = null;
            try {
                socket = new Socket(host, SERVERPORT);
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            while (true) {
                String msg = null;
                try {
                    msg = in.readLine();
                    //msgList.add(msg);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (msg == null) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    displayMsg(msg);
                }
            }

        }
    }).start();


}

public void displayMsg(String msg) {
    final String mssg = msg;
    handler.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            tvOutputMessage.setText(tvOutputMessage.getText().toString() + "Server Says: " + mssg + "\n");
        }
    });
}
}
```

> **chat_main_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMyIp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""/>
    </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSendMsg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:text="send"
        android:layout_weight="0" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etInputMesage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvOutputMessage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what is in client how to find it ?  ActivityMain.ipToConnect